# Using a .sty file with if-else options

Tags: packages, package-options

I have a .sty file with the following part:

```
% a.sty
...
  \if@twoside
     \setlength\oddsidemargin   {36.1\p@}
     \setlength\evensidemargin  {0\p@}
     \setlength\marginparwidth {40\p@}
  \else
     \setlength\oddsidemargin   {36.1\p@}
     \setlength\evensidemargin  {36.1\p@}
     \setlength\marginparwidth  {40\p@}
  \fi
...
```

I now want to use this a.sty with the 'if' branch. How should I property do it in my main Tex file?

```
% how to use choose 'if' branch?
\usepackage{a}
```

Comment: `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` (or whatever class you are using) all the standard classes set `\if@twoside` true with that option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks this works!

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
```

(or whatever class you are using).

All the standard classes set `\if@twoside` true with that option.